# How to share the post to internet from game in unity3d?

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I want to share the score from my game to social network like FB, Twitter, dll,,
and i use Native Android Plugin.

In the tutorial they said we can share it with just using this function

```
AndroidSocialGate.StartShareIntent("Hello Share Intent", "This is my text to share");
```

when i use it, theres no error, but when i call it nothing happen too..

is there someone know where's the problem?
or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with native android plugin.
Check weather android menifest merging is needed with other plugins.

[Merging Adnroid Native Plugin 1](https://unionassets.com/android-native-plugin/merging-manifest-with-another-android-plugin-104)

[Merging Android Native Plugin 2](https://unionassets.com/android-native-plugin/can-i-use-this-plugin-with-other-android-plugins-103)

Use this links

Also Check in the logcat what the debug messages say for plugin if there is any error while you can get it there. Remember to use logcat for plugins as most errors unity wont be able to show.